# How can you cut out a range of lines surrounding keyword in bash?

Tags: bash

So, I know that to cut out lines matching a keyword, you can do something like

```
grep -v "keyword"
```

And you can get lines before and after with grep using the -A and -B switches... However, when you combine the two...

```
grep -A 15 -B 1 -v "keyword"
```

It does NOT cut out all 16 lines of text from the output... It actually doesn't appear to do anything at all, near as I can tell. Is there some other way I can get this functionality, where I can search for a keyword, and then remove defined surrounding content?

Comment: Those answers don't use grep.

Comment: Don't think of `-v` as removing lines; it just inverts the selection of lines. The `-A` and `-B` options always show context, in this case showing the lines that surround each line that does *not* contain "keyword".

Answer (score 0):

Use grep twice:

```
grep -v "$(grep -A 15 -B 1 'keyword' FILE)" FILE
```

to operate on file named FILE.

If it needs to work on stdout, first write it to FILE using

```
> FILE
```

then do the above.